# Regex for a Person Name

Tags: java, regex, validation

I wanted to make a TextField validation for a person name. I wanted to have person name to be valid if:

1. it contains only english alphabets `a-z`, `A-Z`
2. it may contain multiple space characters
3. it may contain any no. of dot characters for the names like `A.B. Devilliers`

What I have tried?

```
NAME_REGEX="(\\w|\\s|(\\.))+"
```

Note: I am working in Java.

When I have `NAME_REGEX="(\\w|\\s)+"` then rules 1. and 2. are followed but I also want the 3. rule.

Comment: Does `NAME_REGEX` do what you want?

Comment: What do you do with persons, that do have an name, that does not follow those rules? Containing characters like "üöäßí" ...

Espescially with *NAMES* the spelling can be very important...

Comment: Maybe with `NAME_REGEX="(\\w|\\s|([A-Z]\\.))+"` to ensure the dot is after an uppercase letter :) As said by DThought, your rules can be problematic with few names (mine for example contains some '-')

Comment: @Nizil: Then what should be the REGEX for name, according to you?

Comment: @eternal_developer: i don't think you can come up with an regex for name validation.
Make something up, that will accept this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_popular_given_names might be a start, if you insist on validation. I'm not sure whether there are names that legitimatly contain numbers... (like a king, (Grande  4.) ?)

Comment: Trying to enforce rules on something which isn't governed by rules is always going to end badly. You don't know better than everybody else what is a 'valid' name and what isn't (there's no such thing as a *valid name*) - if I really wanted to I could legally change my name to something daft like j0N4tH/-\n, which would then mean I either can't use your application, or I'm forced to enter incorrect data. *Don't try and enforce rules on things that aren't governed by rules*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This regex for java:::

```
   NameRegex =  ^^[a-z A-Z\\.\\s]+$
```

Comment: No it will take any no of space

Comment: I think it should be '^[a-z A-Z\\.\\s]+$' . You are adding an extra ^

Comment: ya you can replace it ^^[a-z A-Z\\.\\s]+$ with ^[a-z A-Z\\.\\s]+$ no change in output.....

Comment: please write some explanation for your answer.

Comment: this regex will take 
It contains only english alphabets a-z, A-Z
It may contain multiple space characters
It may contain any no. of dot characters

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to specify what should be allowed in a name, so trying to tweak too much is probably counter-productive. If anything, I would err on the side or allowing more things.

It looks to me like you want something like this:

```
(?i)^(?:[a-z]+(?: |\. ?)?)+[a-z]$
```

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT1kC8), see which names are allowed.

- I am assuming you want to start and end with a letter
- You have not specified that any letter must specifically be in upper case, so this will accept `aLan parsoN`
- If you want to allow quotes or other chars, let me know.

**How it works:**

- `(?i)` puts us in case-insensitive mode
- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?:[a-z]+(?: |\. ?)?)+` matches {any letters, optionally followed by a space or dot or dot-space}, once or more
- `[a-z]$` ensures that the last character is a letter

Comment: you are some what right but I also want names without dots as in "**Virat Kohli**"

Comment: Yes this allows names without dots. Posting a demo and explanation in a moment. :)

Comment: Okay, added demo and explanation, let me know if you need any tweaks. :)

Comment: Excellent but you are not allowing multiple spaces (which a lazy android app user may do). but Excellent, I dont have privileges to up vote your answer.